# can't connect to mongoDB: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB using Node.js. This is the code (Listing 13.1 from Daley et al. "Node.js, MongoDB, and Angular Web Development"):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
Server = require('mongodb').Server;
var client = new MongoClient();
client.connect('mongodb://dbadmin:test@localhost:27017/testDB',
{poolSize:5, reconnectInterval:500},

function(err,db){

    if(err){
        console.log("connection failed via client obj.");
    }else{
        console.log("connected via client obj...");
        db.logout(function(err,result){
            if(!err){
                console.log("logged out via client obj...");
            }
            db.close();
            console.log("connection closed...");
        });
    }
});
```

I get the following error:

```
return (connectionString.startsWith('mongodb://') ||
                             ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'startsWith')
    at connectionStringHasValidScheme
```

I tried to connect to MongoDB with Node.js but keep getting the error.

Comment: You should not print static text `"connection failed via client obj."`, because it does not tell you any details about the error. Better use `"connection failed via client obj: " + err.message`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const client = new MongoClient('mongodb://dbadmin:test@localhost:27017/testDB');

async function main() {
  // Use connect method to connect to the server
  await client.connect();
  console.log('Connected successfully to server');
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('documents');

  // the following code examples can be pasted here...

  return 'done.';
}
```

[Reference](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/6.3/#md:connect-to-mongodb)

Comment: It works, thank you.

Comment: @jhs, I am glad & I hope you understood what did not worked as well.